# How to check an item exists with powershell without raising an error?

Tags: powershell-extensions

In Sitecore Powershell extensions I can use

`If ( Get-Item ...)`

to return true if an item exists or false if it doesn't, but if the item isn't found then it outputs an error message as well.

Is there a way of checking for an item's existence that doesn't output an error message (and is possibly less intensive than using Get-Item - I only need to know if it's there or not, I don't need to instantiate it)?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try this

```powershell
$database = "master"
$homeItem = "$($database):\sitecore\content\home123"
$homeExists = Test-Path -Path $homeItem
```

Answer (score 12):

An alternative would be to run the `Get-Item` command and provide the necessary `ErrorAction` parameter to hide the output.

```powershell
# Variable $item will contain the object if found.
if(($item = Get-Item -Path "master:\content\home1" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)) {
    $item
} else {
    Write-Host "Does not exist."
}
```

Sometimes you may also see the parameter shortened to `-ea 0`.

Answer (score 1):

The above answers above work well if we Get-Item using the Path but unfortunately I was only supplied with item IDs and not Path. So if we Get-Item using ID, exception always occurs even after using -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue. For this case, we will have to use the try-catch block as below -

```
try { 
        $currentItem = Get-Item -Path "master:" -ID $row.ID -Language "*" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    }
    catch { 
        Write-Log "Item with ID $($row.ID)doesnt exist!"
        continue
    }
```

Sharing this answer in case you are in same situation as me and you are only supplied with Id of item.