# Determining whether item has been published

Tags: powershell-extensions

Is there an easy way using SPE to determine whether an item has been published?

Comment: check the web database or target database. take a look at this answer https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/7624/how-to-check-an-item-exists-with-powershell-without-raising-an-error?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

If you are interested seeing an example visible through the gutter, enable the **Publishing Status Gutter** module.

[image]

If you would like to try it out:

- navigate to the Script Library
- enable the Publishing Status Gutter module
- rebuild the integration points
- enable the gutter.

[image]

Comment: I wanted to export published content to an excel spreadsheet to allow the business to review what's in Sitecore so this option wouldn't help. However, the content editing team have asked for greater visibility of published items so I will turn on this functionality. Thanks!

Comment: @Ged if that is your requirement, please update the question to make that clear so that someone can answer the specific requirement